# Remove &iuml;&iquest;&frac12;s characters from html text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I am parsing the html files using nokogiri, and I want the html text from the file by removing some elements. I have achieved this. But the problem is when I am getting the html its showing me the `&iuml;&iquest;&frac12;s` this characters.

How could I remove this? Because when the above characters displaying on browser showing the wrong text. So how I replace this characters ?

Answer (score 0):

I use this ActionView::Helper => simple_format(text)

In the view, insert the embedded Ruby statement (with your text pointer)...

```
 <%= simple_format(@article.content) %>
```

Tidys up text for html display.

Specification here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html